# SpriteKit Layout Issues

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, autolayout

I started SpriteKit programming using Xcode 6+, and when adding nodes or any objects from code, I am having problem with their layouts when changing between devices (4',3.5', 4.7'...). How can I fix this problem and make the any game universal looking good on all devices?

Comment: you should try the game level helper

Comment: Be specific. What kind of problems?

Comment: When programming using Storyboards, applying autolayout is done on visible objects. How can I apply something similar to autolayout but in SpriteKit, knowing that objects arent visible until runtime (no storyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic solution here. Sprite kit is all manual layout. It makes sense if you think about it because making a landscape game automatically work in portrait mode doesn't make sense. You will need to manually establish all co-ordinates and scaling yourself.